# Translation Algorithm for CILP model (Garcez, Lamb, Gabbay) - why difference in answer between my implementation and the answer from the book?

Tags: logic, neurosymbolic-ai

I have implemented the Translation algorithm for CILP (Connectionist Inductive Learning and Logic Programming model by Garcez, Lamb and Gabbay) from their book "Neural-Symbolic Cognitive Reasoning"

The paper which describes the example Neural Network can be found here:

[https://www.staff.city.ac.uk/~aag/papers/cilp.pdf](https://www.staff.city.ac.uk/%7Eaag/papers/cilp.pdf)

My implementation can be found here:

https://github.com/nravindranath10/CILP_Translation_Algorithm

While the book claims that the 2 iterations are required for the Neural Network to converge to the final answer which is {B}, in my code the Neural Network seems to take only 1 iteration to converge to the same answer {B}. I have highlighted the "m = 2" line in my attached image from the book.

I would like to understand if I am going wrong somewhere in my implementation.

Thanks,
Ravi[image]

Comment: I don't see any question being asked here. Can you please edit your post to **ask a specific question explicitly** and put it in the title too?

Comment: my question was that my code was taking only 1 iteration to reach the answer while the book says that 2 iterations are required to reach the answer. So I wanted to know there was anything wrong with my code logic. However, now I have figured out the fallacy in my code and have made a small modification to the logic of the code. So now my code too requires 2 iterations to reach the answer. So now my implementation is in agreement with author. So, closing this ticket now.